# I want to fill circles with different colors using array in turtle python

Tags: python, arrays, turtle-graphics

[image]
I made 4 circles like that using hardcode for each circle, but it's not efficient.

this is my code, but I am confused how to access the array of color & the array of coordinate x & y, so that it can be accessed throug all the index.

```
from turtle import *
setup()
title('4 CIRCLES')

col = ['yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'red']
x = [100,65,30,5]
y = [100,65,30,5]

def lingkaran(number, rad = 50) :
    for cir in range(number) :
        penup()
        goto(x, y)
        pendown()
        color(col)
        begin_fill()
        circle(rad)
        end_fill()
        lingkaran(4)

hideturtle()
done()
```

I want to make it simple by accessing the arrays, hope someone can help.
Thanks

Comment: I did indentation; but your code is wrong here. You're not using values inside of lists but using the whole list as argument which will surely cause error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we're looking at a fixed distance between circles, I'd toss the array of coordinates in favor of a starting position and an offset.  Then I'd loop simply on the array of colors:

```
from turtle import *

title('4 CIRCLES')

COLORS = ['yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'red']

def lingkaran(colors, position, offset, radius, pen_width=3):
    width(pen_width)

    for color in colors:
        penup()
        goto(position)
        pendown()

        fillcolor(color)
        begin_fill()
        circle(radius)
        end_fill()

        position += offset

lingkaran(COLORS, Vec2D(-100, 100), Vec2D(35, -35), 50)

hideturtle()
done()
```

[image]

But there are lots of ways to go about a problem like this.